# Workflow Task to Upload File

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am working in SP2013 designer and would like to set up a step in a workflow where the user has to upload a file with a specific name to trigger the next step in the workflow.  Any help with this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the workflow associated to a list, content type or is it a site workflow?

Comment: It's associated to a list

Comment: Ok, then how is a uploaded file related to the item the workflow will run on? Would it be an item attachment or a fie uploaded into a separate library?